# Trying to print or use a Bit type in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, bit

Im using PHP and selecting a Bit value from a MySql database. I cant seem to be able to use the Bit type. 
I cant print or convert it to another type, well not that I can find anyway. Any idea?

Comment: You really should show us some code...

Comment: what would you get back from calling `var_dump($row['bitValue'])`

Answer (score 1):

if(ord($myvarfromdb))
{ $myvarfromdb = "Yes"; }
else
{ $myvarfromdb = "No"; }

works :)
issues closed :) thanks guys